# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cust_name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am submitting the form in nodejs wanted to save customer name in mongodb but it showing an error on cmd "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cust_name' of undefined" can any one help me this

```js
/*--------------------list.model.js-------*/
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var leadlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cust_name: {
        type: String
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Leadlist', leadlistSchema);

/*----------------------index.js----------------*/
app.post('/leadtest',jsonParser, function(req, res){
    const doc = new Leadlist();
    doc.cust_name = req.body.cust_name;
doc.save(function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(error);
        }
        else{
            res.send("Data inserted");
        }
    });;
});
```

Comment: `req.body.cust_name` is printing any value? With `console.log(req.body.cust_name)`

Comment: "console.log(req.body.cust_name)"  showing "undefined"

Comment: so `cust_name` may not been passed from front-end

Comment: "<form action="/leadtest" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="cust_name" class="fadeIn second" 
name="cust_name" placeholder="Full name"></input>
</form>" this is an fornt end coding but it seems does't have an error

Comment: Are you passing by jquery or react?

Comment: in front end i am using express-handlerbar

Comment: You need `express.json()` or similar middleware, to parse request bodies.